# Fill background with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you strech a background image in a way that when a user scrolls down the backgorund is still the same and does not end with a black white space as the background if the user scrolls more that the screen size

I tried this styling but when testing with firefox I keep on scrolling into a white background

```
          <style>
          .background {
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            height:  100%;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
           
            }
          </style>
```

```
{% block content%}
<div class="background">
            <canvas width="max-width" height="max-height" id="canv" />
</div>
{% for product  in all products %}
<div style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:5px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; float: left;">
            <div class="card" style="width: 20rem; height: 20rem;  opacity: 0.7; "  >
                <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{product.title}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{product.description}}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{product.link}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock%}
```

in the js file reponsible for creating the canvas I used the height as `screen.height` same for width but still same result with the white space when scrolling down

for the back end I am using flask

Comment: Are you looking for position fixed, so that the background div stays where it is on screen all the time?

Comment: no i want to have a background that keeps on growing when user scrolls down

Comment: The background seems to be being provided by a canvas rather than a background-image so I don't understand your use of background-size: cover. What is drawing on the canvas and does that change as the user scrolls or is the canvas just to stretch (vertically)?

Comment: the canvas is meteor shower that does not have impact effect it just escapes the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your canvas is sth similar to this

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canv');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const w = canvas.width = screen.width;
const h = canvas.height = screen.Height;
```

try [this](http://619847/nsurl-is-not-find-when-url-string-with-space-parameter/12620024#12620024), by changing the canvas height to be that of the scroll value you get a web page filled to the bottom of the page

you can do sth like this

```
let scrollHeight = Math.max(
  document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
  document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
  document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
);
```

and use `scrollHeight` as the height for your canvas